# Multicollinearity in Linear Mixed model

Tags: r, lme4

I am fitting the following `lmer` models in R:

```
lmer(rt~deadline*cond+age+(1+deadline|task/pp), REML=FALSE) ##Model 1
lmer(rt~deadline+cond+age+(1+deadline|task/pp), REML=FALSE) ##Model 2
```

Where `rt` is reaction time, `deadline` has 2 levels short or long, `cond` also has two levels: easy or hard. In the research I have conducted, 30 subjects have done 4 tasks. Per task subjects did 50 trials in each of the four levels (short/easy, long/easy, short/hard, long/hard). In my model above, I have random intercepts for person and task, and random slopes for person and task on deadline.
So in total they have done 800 trials. Accuracy and reaction time were recorded. I am interested if complexity (=`cond`) and urgency (=`deadline`) have a (interaction) effect on reaction time. Since there might be a interaction effect, I fitted the first model with the interaction, and I compare it with a second model without the interaction.

When I run the first model, I get the following output:

`lm.rtfnew <- lmer(rt~deadline*cond+age+(1+deadline|task/pp), REML=FALSE)
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
summary(lm.rtfnew)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: rt ~ deadline * cond + age + (1 + deadline | task/pp)
 ...
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
   (Intercept)             5.874631   0.669971    8.77
 deadlineshort            -0.375643   0.171779   -2.19
      condhard            -4.685013   0.066538  -70.41
      condeasy            -4.658016   0.066538  -70.01
           age             0.006791   0.018018    0.38
   deadlineshort:condhard  0.007752   0.018960    0.41
 ...
 fit warnings:
     fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient` 

So I have a problem, since for both `deadline` and `cond`, two columns are made, and then these two columns show perfect multicollinearity? Then R fixes it by dropping one column for `deadline`, but not for `cond` (since there is a fixed effect `condhard` and `condeasy`). 
Therefore I have two questions:

1. Why does R doesn't drop a column of `cond`?
2. Do I need to fix it manually?

Comment: Search for "treatment contrasts". One level of `deadline` and one level of `cond` are represented by the intercept.

Comment: So actually there is not a problem? Or do I manually have to create contrasts?

Comment: From what I see here there is no apparent problem. However, I don't have access to your data, so there still might be problems. (I find it suspicious that the hard and easy condition effects are so similar and so strongly correlated. I assume that the third levels is medium.) Contrasts are created automatically. If you don't want treatment contrasts, but some other kind of contrasts, you can adjust that. You could also adjust the base level of the treatment contrasts.

Comment: But that is the strange thing: condition just has two levels, easy and hard (So the correlation should be 1 right?). And there should be one fixed effect right (either condeasy or condhard)...?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (code + data). Without it will be hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: What is the output of `summary(cond)`?

Comment: > summary(cond)
           hard  easy 
  116 10508 10508

Comment: Hard to see from your comment, but apparently there are three levels, i.e., one level appears to be `""`. Those should probably be `NA` values.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to find lay-out for stackflow but couldn't find it. Indeed, there seems to be 116 NA's. I try to remove them with lmer(rt~deadline+cond+deadline*cond+(1+deadline|task/pp), REML=F, na.action=na.omit), but still it does not work. How to proceed?

Comment: They *should* be `NA` values, *but* it doesn't look like they are. Apparently they are a factor level that is an empty character string. Either, fix this during data import or do `cond[cond == ""] <- NA`. (Btw., your data should sit together in a data.frame and you should use the `data` parameter in `lmer`.)

Answer (score 0):

With additional information provided by OP in the comments one problem became apparent: There is a factor level `""` in `cond`. This level is represented by the intercept and "hard" and "easy" rts are quite different from "" rts, but very similar to each other in comparison. These "" values are actually `NA` values and should be encoded as such. If this is done corresponding observations would be removed by `na.action = na.omit`. Doing this might already fix the rank-deficiency problem. If it doesn't, OP could consider scaling variables or dropping the interaction term.

Comment: Thanks! I finally found the problem: I didn't use the correct data.frame. I created it, and then used droplevels to drop indeed the empty character string, but then forget to use that in my lmer function (data=dat). Thanks for your work and energy.